# Looping through Entity Framework complex type

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, entity-framework

Trying to loop through the results of a stored procedure using entity framework. I need to compare the list of communities to the value in a textbox so the user does not enter duplicate communities in the database, using a duplicate flag. I can retrieve my list of communities but I'm having difficulty looping through that list.

```
    Dim duplicate = False
    Dim list = Accommodations.GetCommunities
    For Each n As String In list.CommunityName
        If n = txtCommunities.Text Then
            duplicate = True
        End If
    Next n
```

While debugging I can hover over Accommodations.GetCommunities and see all of the values I need to loop through under the field "CommunityName" but when I step through the loop, the value for n shows up as a single character. Is there a way to turn this result set into a list so that I can loop through each value under "CommunityName"

I've also tried the below code and it sets com equal to the name of the complex type for some reason, but it properly loops through the correct number of items in the list. How can I extract that field to compare it to the textbox?

```
    Dim duplicate = False
    Dim com As String = String.Empty
    Dim list = Accommodations.GetCommunities
    For i As Integer = 0 To list.count - 1
        com = list(i).ToString
        If com = txtCommunities.Text Then
            duplicate = True
        End If
    Next
    Return duplicate
```

---

**FINAL EDIT:**

This is the function I used after. Used the String.Compare() method to compare the strings to ignore the case as well.

```
 Private Function checkDuplicates()
    Dim duplicate = False

    Dim list = Accommodations.GetCommunities 'Put items in a list
    For i As Integer = 0 To list.count - 1 'loop through the list
        If String.Compare(list(i).CommunityName, txtCommunities.Text, True) = 0 Then 'Compare the two strings, comparrison is not case sensitive
            duplicate = True 'set dup flag to true
            Exit For 'exit loop
        End If
    Next
    Return duplicate

End Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it should look something more like

```
Dim duplicate = False
Dim list = Accommodations.GetCommunities
For Each community As [something] In list
    If community.CommunityName = txtCommunities.Text Then
        duplicate = True
    End If
Next n
```

or

```
Dim duplicate = False
Dim list = Accommodations.GetCommunities
For i As Integer = 0 To list.count - 1
    If list(i).CommunityName = txtCommunities.Text Then
        duplicate = True
    End If
Next
Return duplicate
```

Side note: Try to use good variable names instead of just n. Also, when you find a duplicate, you can exit for loop or just return True right away.

Comment: You're second example worked for me thanks! Is there any way I can ignore case when comparing the two? For example if I have New York and new york that would not flag as a duplicate.

Comment: Used the String.Compare() method to compare the two strings to ignore the case when comparing the two !

Answer (score 2):

In the first case you are comparing n to each character in CommunityName. You should do something like:

```
For Each n As String In list
    If n.CommunityName = txtCommunities.Text Then
```

In the second case list(i) is a community in the list. Thus list(i).ToString() shows the name of the variable.

Answer (score 1):

Sample 1

Ther is also option using dictionary, If u have your list as a dictionary u don't need looping after if u wana check add or remove by unique key value

> ```
> Public Class TestClass
>     Property Name As String
> End Class
> Private Function TestFun() As Boolean
>     'Sample List to convert use Accommodations.GetCommunities
>     Dim List As New List(Of TestClass)
>     List.Add(New TestClass With {.Name = "a"})
>     List.Add(New TestClass With {.Name = "b"})
>     'If at Begining all elements by key are unique u can convert to dictionary
> '
> 'From This Point u can map your list in to dictionary Use Accommodations.GetCommunities instant List. and type of what use in this collection replece as TestClass
>     Dim CheckInDictionary As Dictionary(Of String, TestClass) = List.ToDictionary(Function(p) p.Name, Function(p) p)
>     ' After you can us if some key or Id exist
>     Return CheckInDictionary.ContainsKey("a")
> End Function 'Return True
> ```

Sample 2

Ther is Also Another Possibility to Check if List have duplicate, but this is abit more complex.

List have method Contains that check if element exist in said list, so before add new element  you can check if list have it.  To Compare is used Method Equal so if you overide it in your base class you can do special rules for equal.

Like

> ```
> Public Class TestClass
>     Property Name As String
>     Public Overrides Function Equals(obj As Object) As Boolean
>         'IMPORTEND Input is as object if anny case will be somthing diffrent then this type it can meak exception
>         If DirectCast(obj, TestClass).Name = Me.Name Then Return True
>         Return MyBase.Equals(obj)
>     End Function
> End Class
> ```
>
> and after when u atempt to add new element u dolike that
>
> ```
>     Dim NewEle = New TestClass With {.Name = "a"}
>     If Not List.Contains(NewEle) Then
>         List.Add(NewEle)
>     End If
> ```